# Merging navigation row array with default values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, nodes

I am trying to create a node tree for my site navigation rows.

Here is an example parent node with some of the default keys.

```
$allRows['inbox'] = [
    "name"  => 'inbox',
    "icon"  => 'inbox',
    "link"  => 'inbox',
    "badge" => [
        'active'    => true,
        'color'     => 'yellow',
        'text'      => '14',
        'position'  => 'right',
    ],
];
```

And here is an example of a parent node with some children.

```
$allRows['tables'] = [
    "name"  => 'tables.main',
    "icon"  => 'table',
    "index" => [
        [
            'name' => 'tables.normal',
            'link' => 'tables/normal',
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'tables.data-tables',
            'link' => 'tables/data-tables',
            'badge' => [
                'active'    => true,
                'color'     => 'green',
                'text'      => 'v1.10',
                'position'  => 'right',
            ],
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'tables.jquery-grid',
            'link' => 'tables/jquery-grid',
        ],
    ],
];
```

I want all my nodes to fit this default structure.

```
$defaults = [
    "name"       => '',
    "icon"       => '',
    "icon_color" => '',
    "link"       => '#',
    "external"   => false,
    "badge" => [
        'active'    => false,
        'color'     => '',
        'text'      => '',
        'position'  => '',
    ],
    "index"      => [],
];
```

In my navigation class I have `$allRows` declared like above.

I tried to merge the defaults by passing as reference to `mergeWithDefaults($allRows)` method but couldn't accomplish what I wanted.

```
public function mergeWithDefaults(&$navRows)
{
    foreach ($navRows as &$navRow) {
        $navRow = array_merge($this->defaults, $navRow);
        if (! $this->isLeaf($navRow)) {
            $navRow = $this->mergeWithDefaults($navRow['index']);
        }
    }
}

private function isLeaf($navRow)
{
    return empty($navRow['index']);
}
```

Somewhy I am getting nulls as result.

```
array:11 [▼
  "dashboard" => array:7 [▶]
  "inbox" => array:7 [▶]
  "graphs" => null
  "tables" => null
  "forms" => null
  "ui-elements" => null
  "calendar" => array:7 [▶]
  "widgets" => array:7 [▶]
  "app-views" => null
  "gmap-skins" => array:7 [▶]
  "miscellaneous" => null
]
```

What am I missing?

Comment: what is $this->defaults ?

Comment: I edited some of the code while pasting, that referred to $defaults variable I mentioned above.

Comment: you want to covert $allRows to $default structure correct ??

Comment: I wanted that every single row to have the defaults.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it by removing `$navRow =` from `$navRow = $this->mergeWithDefaults($navRow['index']);`.

Since wasn't returning anything it was setting lal my data to null's.

```
public function mergeWithDefaults(&$navRows)
{
    foreach ($navRows as &$navRow) {
        $navRow = array_merge($this->defaults, $navRow);
        if (! $this->isLeaf($navRow)) {
            $this->mergeWithDefaults($navRow['index']);
        }
    }
}
```